# fetch json array and append data in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass a json array to another page with jquery and on that another page I want to bind the data to the respective element.This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'url of the php page',
    data: {'json':jsondata},
    dataType :'json',
    async: false,
    encode: true
}).done(function(data) {
    window.location.href = 'anotherpageurl?res='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

This is the json response from the url that i receive:

```
{
"data": [
{
"full_name": "xxxx",
"employee_id": "xxxxx",
"imageUrl": "xxxx",
"dname": "xxxx"
},
{
"full_name": "xxxxx",
"employee_id": "xxxxx",
"imageUrl": "xxxx",
"dname": "xxxx"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Use the formatting and format your question to make it easier to read, i.e. use code blocks when you type code e.t.c. Also, explain what you have tried, and why that has not worked as expected.

Comment: I have formatted the code....I have the json response but how can i format the json and add it@Cleared

Answer (score 0):

Use data not data(data)

Following information might help you URL encoding refer below,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding